# How to configure a coreaudio HAL plugin

Tags: c++, macos, plugins, core-audio, hal

A while ago I developed a [coreaudio HAL plugin](https://github.com/betabandido/mac2rpi_coreaudio_plugin) in C++ that sends audio from a Mac OS to a Raspberry Pi.

Now, I would like to make some parameters configurable (e.g., the IP address of the RPI). I would like to at least achieve one of the following:

- make the plugin load some configuration file (e.g., from /Library/Preferences)
- have a CLI tool to communicate with the plugin so that the configuration can be changed anytime

I have gone through Apple's documentation, and the only relevant thing I have managed to find is the following paragraph:

> Further, the host process is sandboxed. As such, an AudioServerPlugIn may only read files in its bundle in addition to the system libraries and frameworks. It may not access user documents or write to any filesystem locations other than the system's cache and temporary directories as derived through Apple API. The host provides a means for the plug-in to store and retrieve data from persistent storage.

(see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1811/_index.html).

I have no idea what the last sentence means. Might it refer to a way for the plugin to read data from a file?

Has anyone done anything similar and successfully communicated with the plugin so that it can (re)load its configuration?

Comment: Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html ?

Comment: Also, in the AudioServerPlugIn API there are storage operations available: `CopyFromStorage`, `WriteToStorage`, `DeleteFromStorage`

Comment: Looking at the demo project it seems controlling the state of your drive happens via property operations

Comment: Merging and Motu seem to be doing this using IOKitUserClients (by looking at their plists). See line 49 of AudioServerPlugIn.h

Comment: Thanks for the link @RuurdAdema. I believe that's what I used years ago to create the audio server. And I could not find it anymore. BTW, do you know why Apple states "This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information about Apple SDKs, visit the documentation website." Is there a better (or more supported) way to do this today?

Comment: I'm not completely sure but I think it has to with with the fact that some years ago Apple started working on their new documentation website (https://developer.apple.com/documentation). Over the years API's were slowly added, and some are present but in a very limited way (ie. Core Audio) and for those cases it's more helpful to dive into the raw header files or into the archives.